# Read table from .csv into multiple arrays in SciLab

Tags: arrays, csv, readfile, scilab

I've put together a table with three columns as a .csv file, and I want to read each column into a different array.  I've looked in the SciLab help files and elsewhere on this site, and it looks like this should work:

```
    e=zeros(641,1)          //Initialise array of energy values
    P=zeros(641,1)          //Initialise array of Power values
    mu=zeros(641,1)         //Initialise array of attenuation values
    clc                     //Clear console
    MYDATA = read_csv ('C:\Users\ID914317\Box Sync\PhD\Data\power_atten.csv')       //read in array of energies, powers and attenuation coefficients
    Z=evstr(MYDATA)         //evaluate array of strings into numerical values
    disp(Z)                 //output array to console (debug)
    for i=1:641             //loop through number of rows
        e(i)=Z(1,i)             //assign column 1 values to array of energies
        P(i)=Z(2,i)             //assign column 2 values to array of powers
        mu(i)=Z(3,i)            //assign column 3 values to array of attenuations
    end
    disp(e)
    disp(P)
    disp(mu)
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get the following error message in the console:

```
    e(i)=Z(1,i)             //assign column 1 values to array of energies
                 !--error 21 
    Invalid index.
    at line      10 of exec file called by :    
    lab\absorption interpolation.sce', -1
```

I'm mainly self taught in SciLab, so any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I sorted it out - I had the array reference backwards:

```
    for i=1:641             //loop through number of rows
            e(i)=Z(1,i)             //assign column 1 values to array of energies
            P(i)=Z(2,i)             //assign column 2 values to array of powers
            mu(i)=Z(3,i)            //assign column 3 values to array of 
    end
```

should have been:

```
    for i=1:641             //loop through number of rows
            e(i)=Z(i,1)             //assign column 1 values to array of energies
            P(i)=Z(i,2)             //assign column 2 values to array of powers
            mu(i)=Z(i,3)            //assign column 3 values to array of attenuations
    end
```

Comment: Why do you need the loop at all? More simple & faster: e=Z(1:641,1); P=Z(1:641,2); mu=Z(1:641,3);